# Select options not displaying in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

html :

```
<select id="show_date" data-bind="options:dateOptionsArray,value:selectedDate, event: {change:onChangeDate}"></select>
```

JS:

```
self.dateOptionsArray = ko.observableArray(["Today","7 Days","30 Days", "Select Date Range"]);
self.selectedDate = ko.observable();
console.log(self.dateOptionsArray());

self.onChangeDate = function() {
        console.log("Selcted Date Range :");
        console.log(self.selectedDate());
        
        };
```

This is not displaying the select options at all. It used to display a week ago, but now it's not in my code. What mistake am I making ? I want a drop-down with dates and the show date should open a popup box to select calender range..

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have posted appears to work ok, but there is no provision in the code provided to populate with dates or show a pop up.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.dateOptionsArray = ko.observableArray(["Today", "7 Days", "30 Days", "Select Date Range"]);
  self.selectedDate = ko.observable();
  console.log(self.dateOptionsArray());

  self.onChangeDate = function() {
    console.log("Selcted Date Range :");
    console.log(self.selectedDate());

  };
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select id="show_date" data-bind="options:dateOptionsArray,value:selectedDate, event: {change:onChangeDate}"></select>
```